# Am I waiting too long for propagation time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I registered domain ending with `reviews` from AWS Route 53.
And mix up with another cloud-based VM brand. I use Digital Ocean in this time.
I put `A` record point to my IP address. And it has been 2 days by now with my settings. Then I start to investigate what's wrong with my DNS?

```
KrungThep:~ sarit$ nslookup herr.reviews
Server:     203.144.206.29
Address:    203.144.206.29#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   herr.reviews
Address: 217.70.184.38

KrungThep:~ sarit$ nslookup herr.reviews ns-664.awsdns-19.net
Server:     ns-664.awsdns-19.net
Address:    205.251.194.152#53

Name:   herr.reviews
Address: <my.correct.ip.address>

KrungThep:~ sarit$ nslookup herr.reviews ns-167.awsdns-20.com
Server:     ns-167.awsdns-20.com
Address:    205.251.192.167#53

Name:   herr.reviews
Address: <my.correct.ip.address>

KrungThep:~ sarit$ nslookup herr.reviews ns-1339.awsdns-39.org
Server:     ns-1339.awsdns-39.org
Address:    205.251.197.59#53

Name:   herr.reviews
Address: <my.correct.ip.address>

KrungThep:~ sarit$ nslookup herr.reviews ns-1615.awsdns-09.co.uk
Server:     ns-1615.awsdns-09.co.uk
Address:    205.251.198.79#53

Name:   herr.reviews
Address: <my.correct.ip.address>
```

`Route53`

```
----------------------------------------------
|Name          |Type|  Value        |     TTL|
----------------------------------------------
|herr.reviews  | A  |  xxx.189.83.130 |   300|
|herr.reviews  | NS| ns-664.awsdns-19.net. ns-167.awsdns-20.com. ns-1339.awsdns-39.org. ns-1615.awsdns-09.co.uk. | 60|
|herr.reviews| SOA|ns-664.awsdns-19.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400| 60| 
|backend.herr.reviews| A| xxx.189.83.130|300|
-----------------------------------------------
```

Seems ok since AWS DNS knows my correct IP address. The problem would be propagation time.

@RalfFriedl `herr.reviews` is my domain name. It is Thai language. As far as I known it is not an offend word and I started to uncensored it because of my laziness

```
KrungThep:~ sarit$ host -var herr.reviews demand.alpha.aridns.net.au.
Trying "herr.reviews"
Using domain server:
Name: demand.alpha.aridns.net.au.
Address: 37.209.192.7#53
Aliases:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17614
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;herr.reviews.          IN  ANY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
herr.reviews.       86400   IN  NS  c.dns.gandi.net.
herr.reviews.       86400   IN  NS  a.dns.gandi.net.
herr.reviews.       86400   IN  NS  b.dns.gandi.net.

Received 91 bytes from 37.209.192.7#53 in 88 ms
```

Unfortunately. None of my IP address in the list.

**Update:**
I found the `a.dns.gandi.net, b.dns.gandi.net, c.dns.gandi.net`. They are in the other page!
Route53>Domains>Registered domains>Name servers

**Questions:**
1. Am I miss something in my DNS record?
2. If not. Is 2 days waiting is normal with propagation time?
3. Since I never have a long propagation time like this. Do I always have to use only `AWS EC2` with Route53?

Comment: `1.` DNS doesn't propagate. `2.` What's the actual domain name so that we can check it?

Comment: @joeqwerty I just update my question. Any information you need I will provide ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
host -var my-domain.reviews. demand.alpha.aridns.net.au.
```

`demand.alpha.aridns.net.au.` is one the the `reviews` DNS servers. You should get some entries of type `NS`. Query each of these servers for your domain. Each of these servers should provide the correct answer. The answer of some AWS DNS server doesn't matter as long as it isn't listed here.

**Edit**

I get the same result for the domain that you get, the dns.gandi.net servers. All of these DNS servers answer with 217.70.184.38. You have to get your address to the dns.gandi.net servers, or you have to change the DNS servers to point to the AWS DNS servers.

Further waiting won't help you.

You can do the kind of check I described here immediately after changing DNS entries. Your changes should be visible immediately. The delay may only apply to DNS resolvers that have cached old data, there you have to wait till it expires. But the authoritative DNS servers always have up to date values.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I don't get any match to my correct IP address. Any information you need. I will provide ASAP

Comment: I expanded the answer.

Comment: I just instantiate EC2 and bind Elastic IP to the given Route53. But `host -var my-domain.reviews. demand.alpha.aridns.net.au.` still give me the `gandi.net` :(

Comment: You can do in EC2 whatever you want, it will not help. Either you tell your registrar to change the DNS servers to AWS DNS servers, or you put your desired data into the dns.gandi.net servers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. AWS UI/UX misled me to configure wrong page. I found the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `a.dns.gandi.net, b.dns.gandi.net, c.dns.gandi.net`. 
They are in the other page!

```
Route53>Domains>Registered domains>Name servers
```

Then change it to your DNS